# How to access a session variable inside a shared sub

Tags: asp.net, session

I have a `session` for storing the `id` of the user

```
  Session("id") = "123"
```

I am using a `shared sub` which accessing the session variable, my code is:

```
 Public Shared Sub check_session()
        MsgBox(Session("id"))
  End Sub
```

it shows the error message : *cannot refer to an instance member from a class within a shared sub*

My question is that : **how can i access a session variable inside a shared sub**, *Is it possible to attach another user id to the session variable*?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

According to the answer provided by **Vignesh Kumar** you can access session variable in shared sub. here i provide answer for second question. your shared function for handle session is like the following:

```
Public Shared Sub check_session()
    MsgBox("Old Session:" & HttpContext.Current.Session("id"))
    HttpContext.Current.Session("id") = HttpContext.Current.Session("id") & "567"
    MsgBox("new Session:" & HttpContext.Current.Session("id"))
End Sub
```